# Use a custom field to set the featured image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I know there were questions before like this, but I did not find the answer for my problem.

I've got a custom field which contains an url of an image. If there is no image set for a post the custom field should be used as the featured image (it will only contain a value if there is no featured image)

I have tried to just insert the image in the single.php if there is no featured image e.g:

```
$myId = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'videourl', true);
if ($myId != null) {
echo '<img id="vidimgsingle" src="'.$myId.'">';
}
```

This works fine for the single post view, but later I want to use get_the_post_thumbnail() to display the post featured images.. So is there a possiblity to set the custom field url as the featured image instead of just inserting it instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> but later I want to use get_the_post_thumbnail() to display the post
>   featured images

Firstly, WordPress only allows a single image as a Featured Image. If you would like to use more than a single image, the [Multiple Post Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/) plugin can help you do that.

Secondly, according to my understanding, you would like to use a custom field URL as the image source if there is no value in the Featured Image. I think the only way to do that is to check for a featured image using the code you described and if it's not available, you can fallback to the Custom Field.

You can also take a look at the [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) function if you know the attachment ID.